# How to keep animation working on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Basically I just add a simple rotate animation on an imageView which is a subview of UICollectionViewCell, the animation works fine, but when I scroll the collection view and scroll back, the animation just stoped. How to solve this problem?
This is what I added to the imageView.

```
let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
rotationAnimation.toValue = Double.pi
rotationAnimation.duration = 2.0
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
view.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: When are you adding this animation? Your code needs more context.

Comment: I add it in func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid scrolling's influence, need to use Runloop and its commonModes, making animation with CADisplayLink can do it:

```
private var _displayLinkForRotation:CADisplayLink?
var displayLinkForRotation:CADisplayLink {
    get{
        if _displayLinkForRotation == nil {
            _displayLinkForRotation = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(excuteAnimations))
            _displayLinkForRotation?.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
        }
        return _displayLinkForRotation!
    }
}

func excuteAnimations() {
    //This function will be called 60 times per second.
    //According to your question, you have 2 seconds to rotate the view to 180 angle. So we rotate 90 angle per second here.
    //self.view could be replaced by another view you want to rotate.
    self.view.transform = self.view.transform.rotated(by: 90.0 / 60.0 / 180.0 * CGFloat.pi)

    let angle = atan2(self.view.transform.b, self.view.transform.a) * (45.0/atan(1.0))
    if (round(angle) >= 180.0) { //Stop when rotated 180 angle
        self.displayLinkForRotation.isPaused = true
    }
}
```

To start animation:

```
self.displayLinkForRotation.isPaused = false
```

To destroy it:

```
self.displayLinkForRotation.invalidate()
_displayLinkForRotation = nil
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! And as you know, I wanna add this to the imageview under UICollectionView, so I modify the function to func excuteAnimations(view:UIView), but then I got an error "terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CADisplayLink transform]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1742028c0'"

Comment: Don't use parameter to pass view, use a global imageView variable instead. The parameter will pass the CADisplayLink itself to the function.

Comment: It's like I wanna add the animation to some imageview in the collection view, so seems like I cannot use the global variables here?

Comment: Usually, UICollectionView contains some UICollectionViewCells, and UICollectionViewCells contains the imageView and other views. You could do this in a cell. A cell has CADisplayLink to animate imageView.

Comment: Thank you so much and Xie Xie

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not added key for animation, which you used when initialising rotationAnimation
change line

```
view.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

to

```
view.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "transform.rotation")
```

Hope it helps